# If ${\text{char}(k) = p}$, and ${p \nmid |G|}$, are two representations of $G$ over $k$ isomorphic iff they have the same Brauer character?

Tags: representation-theory

For a field $K$ of characteristic $0$, two representations of a group over $K$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the same character. Is it true that if ${\text{char}(k) = p\nmid |G|}$, then two representations of $G$ over $k$ are isomorphic iff they have the same Brauer character?

Answer (score -2):

This is self-evident due to the fact that k is always algebraically closed so it is confirmed by Zariskei's lemma $\Box$

Comment: Where does it say in the post that $k$ is assumed to be algebraically closed? (Certainly, there are many fields of characteristic $p > 0$ which are not algebraically closed.) And which lemma of Zariski's are you referring to?

Comment: @AlexWertheim Do I have to explain everything?...